# how can I connect to an ec2 instance which is running on a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, private, subnet

how can I connect to an EC 2 instance running in a private subnet using putty. I don't understand what it needs to get connected as I am new to it

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has [some great documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html) on this, covering just about any OS or requirement you may have.

Of particular interest to you might be part 2 of that page: Connection to an instance.

Comment: I went through that, I am able to connect my public instance but I want to connect my private instance by public instance, which I am not able to.